# Как предотвратить "вытаскивание" вверх?

Tags: css, html5, svg

Пишу среду визуального программирования, есть некие блоки
Они состоят из div, в нем svg и p
p - текст блока
пользователь может добавлять блоки в блоки при помощи элементов `<b class=".se-input-container">`

но при перетаскивании одного такого блока в другой, дочерний (новый) выталкивается наверх
Как починить это?
[image: Структура блоков]

CSS:

```
.se-input-container {
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-width: 5rem;
    width: auto;
    min-height: 1.5rem;
    height: auto;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


.se-action .se-input-container,.se-event .se-input-container {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.3rem
}
.se-input-container:empty {
  margin-top: 0rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px
}
.se-action .se-input-container .se:first-of-type, .se-event .se-input-container .se:first-of-type {
    margin-top: -1.5rem !important;
    margin-left: -8px !important;
    transform: scale(1.0);
}

.se-include .se-input-container .se {
  margin-top: 0.5rem !important;
  margin-left: 1rem !important;
  transform: scale(0.999) !important;
}

.se-input-container {
  padding: 0.1rem;
  padding-top: 0.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.9rem;
}

.se-action .se-input-container,.se-event .se-input-container {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.3rem
}
.se-input-container:empty {
  margin-top: 0rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px
}
```

Comment: Причём тег svg ?

Comment: А к какому html эти стили применяются?